# Error while calling R in PHP

Tags: php, r

I am generating jpeg image in R script which is called in php using system command.

**rscript.R**

```
jpeg(file="plot.jpeg")
plot(1:40)
rect(1, 5, 3, 7, col="gray")
dev.off()
```

**mycode.php**

```
<?php 
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "Helllo world\n";
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
system('/usr/bin/local/Rscript rscript.R');
?>
```

**Error message:**
unable to open the device

Comment: Most likely a permission issue. Keep in mind that the http server process is executed under another user account then you usually would execute your script.

Comment: how can i fix this issue?

Comment: We cannot tell you. We do not know the permissions on your system, only you can tell. Keep in mind that we cannot look over your shoulder, we only have the information you give, which is minimal. I suggest you start by checking the permissions of that file and the containing folder. Will be process executed under the http servers user account be able to write that file? If not, then you have to change that, right?

Comment: @arkascha i checked i chaned the permision of folder by using sudo chmod 777 but still same error. one more thing i noticed plot is generated by www-data while user is mandata (folder owned by user). Is this causing any issue? Also it create jpeg image with '0' size.

Comment: If it created a file then the process is able to write the file. So that is not the issue. I did not know that, you did not provide that information before. I cannot follow your statements about user accounts: again: sorry, but we cannot look over your shoulder. I don't know what you mean by "plot" and what that user account "mandata" actually is.

Comment: I suggest you try the following: you change your user identify inside a terminal emulator to that of the http server (probably `www-data`). Then you navigate to the correct folder and execute the r script. What happens?

Comment: @arkascha i change the permission   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data temp but when i execute the script using browser same error. but when i try to run on terminal it generates the plot but last time it was also same.

Comment: "last time it was also same"? What do you mean by that? That it also fails? If so, what error did you get?

Comment: @arkascha It was able to generate plot in the folder when i used command line Rscript mycode.R and now also it can generate plot as www-data as user.

Comment: Both by using the PHP script? Or just by executing the `R` script?

Comment: @arkascha can u pls try your side the same script and php code. I think it is generalized problem.

Comment: @arkascha it never works by using php scirpt through browser. It works when i run Rscript using terminal.

Comment: What I ask is: what happens if you run the php script in a terminal?

Comment: @arkascha when i run php script it works fine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132697/discussion-on-question-by-man-data-error-while-calling-r-in-php).